# how to fetch nested JSON values in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, group-by, jsonparser

I am trying to fetch all the **state** parameter values for each id - **2434,78657**.Kindly help me out how to do this in typescript.As it is a nested JSON, I am unable to fetch these values

**JSON Request**:

```
                        { 
                           "2434":[ 
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"90989",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{  
                                        "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"InProgress"}
                                 }
                              },
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"6576",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                       "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"InProgress"
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"6576",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                       "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"Pending"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ],
                           "78657":[ 
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"6576",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                       "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"Pending"
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"6576",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                       "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"Completed"
                                    }
                                 }
                              },
                              { 
                                 "eventId":"6576",
                                 "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                                 "eventType":"yyyy",
                                 "event":{ 
                                    "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                       "priority":"1",
                                       "state":"Failed"
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
```

Desired Output:

For example, for id 2434, array with all the state parameter values has to be returned.

[InProgress, InProgress, Pending]

Comment: i guess your JSON is not in correct format to iterate over it.

Comment: JSON is edited a bit. Please find it

Answer (score 3):

Here is your required answer,

This answer is **`made dynamic`** so that you can send have any number of keys in your **`Object`** and **it still returns the state value of all the keys** by nested looping.

The piece of code that does magic for you,

```
let object = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(test)) { 
    for (let value of test[key]) { 
        object[key] = object[key] || []
        object[key].push(value['event']['ServiceOrder']['state']
        )
     } 
 }
```

**The code execution:**

```js
let test = {
"2434":[
{ 
    "eventId":"90989",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{  
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"InProgress"}
    }
},
{ 
    "eventId":"6576",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{ 
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"InProgress"
    }
    }
},
{ 
    "eventId":"6576",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{ 
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"Pending"
    }
    }
}
],
"78657":[ 
{ 
    "eventId":"6576",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{ 
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"Pending"
    }
    }
},
{ 
    "eventId":"6576",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{ 
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"Completed"
    }
    }
},
{ 
    "eventId":"6576",
    "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
    "eventType":"yyyy",
    "event":{ 
    "ServiceOrder":{ 
        "priority":"1",
        "state":"Failed"
    }
    }
}
]
}
let object = {};
for (let key of Object.keys(test)) { 
    for (let value of test[key]) { 
        object[key] = object[key] || []
        object[key].push(
            value['event']['ServiceOrder']['state']
        )
     } 
 } 
console.log(object);
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Here is the O/P:

> {   "2434": [
>       "InProgress",
>       "InProgress",
>       "Pending"   ],   "78657": [
>       "Pending",
>       "Completed",
>       "Failed"   ] }

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=77&ssc=18&pln=77&pc=13#code/DYUwLgBGIM6QvBA3gKAEQCYAsBmLaAuAbRSQhQkojRADcQA7MASQBNC0BOABk4A5OaADQUqNekwAqASwC2IDhm4BGTgFplGDcsnLlBJQQCsOANTcsBbt2GjK4xmEkBPAA4KCaZ9%20e2q1OkdCMjtqAGUQACdaaQBjEAB5SNYo4MpQ-zRXSOkAexywX09lP38xOABDaA5mBgAFSNyAc0jYGDQAX1CujpEQzMCmNg4ANiMAdhHS%200GnOQ9MFXVNbV19QxNzS2tpgIknNwWfXxEB-bTQtAjouMTk1IJ%20svtsvIKitBLT5%20pK6s9ag1mq0YO1uuDeqRyGdHMNPGNJrsHFJ5oolhotHo1gZuMYzBYrDZvjN9i53BxjkjZhdMtcYvEkilIjSflkcvlpIUOF8MuUwFUFnVGKxpAwmmhwf4eigALoiNDjPgIwhEchPEmw9jwiZTYl7RwyeRo1QY1Z6HF4raEqmkw4Unw2oKPaFiOm3RkPdVlNlvTkfHk-X78-5oIUMEViiVSiF9F0aoZatAI3WXWaGhZKE0rLHmjb47ZE1O28meSl65FgFn2N0M%207M528l7s97c3aZP4LADCuVkrlA0HYkqoPVjRc1ox1jpRRs8meWmJ0udxmwJO3LabtpYd6-ODdpUXpdyZVe9rw5XOKbb5Ao4ADEKtJQIPo9GujKUF1%20xBcgAjABWICxAgyAdAA3CgABm%20QQAAFF%20ADWIDON%20EEQAk-6AWAAB0iHODAMHQHAACURHIHGEBQZEsFfrQFTAAAriAKFQLAYBELhMqkV6-i-gBQHsUhMoQIgvGYQJzhCQAPpJEBEO%20gaifxHFYa49EwAAFjBjZlLRDEgEQADkswGTKhk1keUQmYZHYmdpREZB00KOSgsS5AwMC5KAWHAM0MGKWARGgUAA)

Comment: @SnehaAitha, Glad to help you. You can accept my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: @Sneha Aitha, did you stuck anywhere? is this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

i think this one is help you.
first of all decode json.

```php
$result =  json_decode($row[1]);
echo $result->{'2434'}[0]->event->ServiceOrder->{'**state**'};
```

results is below.

```
answer: InProgress
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one, here you have to pass particular id (example 2434) from which you need status.
Just pass the id and it will return the status in the form of an array.

```
function getStatusFromId(id: number){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let idObject = NotificationData[id];
    let arrayOfStatus = new Array();
    idObject.forEach((data) => {
      arrayOfStatus.push(data.event.ServiceOrder["**state**"])
    })
    resolve(arrayOfStatus);
  })
}


getStatusFromId(id)
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

```
let NotificationData = { 
                       "2434":[ 
                          { 
                             "eventId":"90989",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{  
                                    "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"InProgress"}
                             }
                          },
                          { 
                             "eventId":"6576",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                   "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"InProgress"
                                }
                             }
                          },
                          { 
                             "eventId":"6576",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                   "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"Pending"
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       ],
                       "78657":[ 
                          { 
                             "eventId":"6576",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                   "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"Pending"
                                }
                             }
                          },
                          { 
                             "eventId":"6576",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                   "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"Completed"
                                }
                             }
                          },
                          { 
                             "eventId":"6576",
                             "eventTime":"2019-12-11T11:20:53+04:00",
                             "eventType":"yyyy",
                             "event":{ 
                                "ServiceOrder":{ 
                                   "priority":"1",
                                   "**state**":"Failed"
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       ]
                    };
```